# How to bind CommandParameter to viewCell Label in ListView (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I'm trying to make grouped ListView for meals and foods with Add Food button for each meal. But when Add Food command is executed I don't know to which meal should I add the food. So I thought it would be good to pass the meal name as a parameter but I don't know how.

This is the ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel : BaseViewModel
{      
    public FoodViewModel()
    {
        this.AddFood = new Command<string>(this.OnAddFood);
        this.MealGroups = new ObservableCollection<MealGroup>();
    }
    public ObservableCollection<MealGroup> MealGroups { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddFood { get; private set; }
    private void OnAddFood(string param)
}
```

This is the MealGroup

```
public class MealGroup : ObservableCollection<Food>
{
    public string MealName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Food> Foods => this;
}
```

This is the ListView

```
<StackLayout x:Name="MealLayout" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button x:Name="AddMealButton" Text="Add Meal" Command="{Binding AddMeal}"/>

            <ListView x:Name="MealGroupsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding MealGroups}" IsGroupingEnabled="true">
                <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout x:Name="MealInfoLayout" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Label x:Name="MealNameLbl" Text="{Binding MealName}" />

                                <StackLayout>
                                    <StackLayout.BindingContext>
                                        <local:FoodViewModel/>
                                    </StackLayout.BindingContext>
                                    <Button x:Name="AddFoodCommand" 
                                        Text="Add Food"
                                        Command="{Binding AddFood}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding }"/>
                                </StackLayout>

                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label x:Name="FoodNameLbl" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass the name of the property as the `Path` of your `Binding`:

```xml
<Button x:Name="AddFoodCommand" 
        Text="Add Food"
        Command="{Binding AddFood}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding MealName}"/>
```

Your `AddFood` command will be called with the `MealName` property as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

There's one more better way to access whole object(not only name)

```
<Button x:Name="AddFoodCommand" 
        Text="Add Food"
        Command="{Binding AddFood}"
        CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
    />
```

Through this,CommandParameter will return whole item

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, I should add a foodId on the  class. It's more efficient to find the item back with such an instruction :

```
Mg = MealGroups.First(o => o.Id == SearchedMealGroupId);
```

In such case, i personnaly use the ItemTapped functionnality of the listview without button (or maybe just an image for UI Experience).

```
<ListView x:Name="listElement" .... ItemTapped="listElement_ItemTapped" ..../>
```

and in the .xmal.cs :

```
private void listElement_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
     int SelectedMealGroupId = ((MealGroup)e.Item).Id; // You are sure of the type of e.Item !
     ....
     // You can call methods of the VM with :
     ((ViewModel)BindingContext).OnAddFood(SelectedMealGroupId); // Int parameter, not string
}
```

Comment: This is bad practice to use the code-behind, the goal of Commands is to avoid this boilerplate code.

Comment: @CorentinPane, I understand. My interrogation is over the performance with long lists. Creating so many buttons will not slow down the list ? I often have lists with 100 or more items and use the search functionnality to access the right items within the list. With my solution, I use only 1 event. What do you think ?